# Minimal good cover of the torus

Tags: gn.general-topology, covering, torus

Recall that an open cover $\mathfrak{U} = \{ U_\alpha \}$ of a manifold $M$ is called a *good cover* if all possible finite intersections $U_{\alpha_1} \cap ... \cap U_{\alpha_n}$ are contractible.

Question: What is the minimum number of open sets required for a good cover of the 2-dimensional torus?

The picture below provides a good cover of the torus (i.e. opposite sides of the parallelogram identified as usual) using 7 open sets (i.e. take sufficiently small open neighbourhoods of the hexagons).  Can one do any better than 7?  If not, how does one prove that 7 is optimal?

[image: Good cover of the torus with 7 open sets (neighbourhoods of the hexagons)]

Comment: Would be nice to see a 3d rendering of that ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't do any better than $7$. This follows from

*Karoubi, Max; Weibel, Charles A.*, [**On the covering type of a space**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4171/LEM/62-3/4-4), Enseign. Math. (2) 62, No. 3-4, 457-474 (2016). [ZBL1378.55002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1378.55002).

in particular Theorem 5.3 in the [arXiv version.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00532)

The *strict covering type* of a space $X$ is the minimal cardinality of a good cover, denoted $\operatorname{sct}(X)$. This is not a homotopy invariant, so Karoubi and Weibel introduce the *covering type*, defined by
$$
\operatorname{ct}(X)=\min\{\operatorname{sct}(X')\mid X'\simeq X\}
$$
Obviously $\operatorname{ct}(X)\leq \operatorname{sct}(X)$. In Theorem 5.3 they use cohomological arguments to show that $\operatorname{ct}(T^2)=7$.

Comment: Great, thanks for the reference!

Comment: Noob question: is this at all related to the fact that all maps on a torus are $7$-colorable but some are not $6$-colorable?

Comment: @GregMartin: Good question. I don't know of a relationship between covering type and chromatic numbers of embedded graphs, but equally I don't know enough to say that such a thing doesn't exist.

Comment: Doesn't the linked paper state the relation of chromatic numbers and covering types on the first page? Or is there some subtle technical detail I missed?